# JPA use both hbm.xml and annotations

Tags: spring, hibernate, entitymanager

I am upgrading my tech stack from Spring 3 to Spring 4 and Hibernate 3 to HIbernate 4.
Currently we are using Hibernate3Support and template, now we are moving to entity manager.
All the db entries are in hbm.xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.mycompany.Employee" table="employee">
    <id column="employeeid" name="employeeID">
      <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="string">
      <column length="100" name="name"/>
    </property>
    <many-to-one class="com.mycompany.Department" name="department"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The configuration was as below:

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="myDataSource"/>
        </property>
        <property name="mappingLocations">
            <value>classpath*:com/**/*.hbm.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">com.mycompany.ExMySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Now we want to use system as with new entities to be made in annotation and along with it we need to support hbm.xml files as we have lots of them and can't convert them manually.
The new configuration:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mycompany"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitPostProcessors">
        <list>
            <bean
class="org.springframework.data.jpa.support.ClasspathScanningPersistenceUnitPostProcessor">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="com.mycompany" />
                <property name="mappingFileNamePattern" value="classpath*:com/**/*hbm.xml" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

When I run the application then get the mapping exception for the entity, please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue in the code, the line should be:

```
<property name="mappingFileNamePattern" value="**/*hbm.xml" />
```